# is it possible for Kaa Sandbox address to be a domain name?

Tags: kaa

Kaa Sandbox address only accepts ip address. Is it somehow possible to replace this with a domain name like eg.mydomain.io or eg.mydomain.com? This is required as my demo applications are unable to communicate with the Sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can use an amazon server like EC2 to host the kaa server and then use amazon route53 to point the domain name to the server. You can also use AWS elastic beanstalk to achieve the same. You would then have a domain name for accessing your kaa sandbox.

Having said that, any demo app would communicate with the kaa server IP address. Not sure why you need a domain name for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Anil. As suggested by you, using DNS entry this can be achieved. The concept of forward lookup comes into action (domain name to IP Address).

Comment: Actually I wanted to host the demo app publicly and sources like ngrok or no-ip was just providing with domain name. To handle this situation I have hosted the application on Google Cloud. Now it is accessible using IP. Cheers!!!

Comment: @SudeepBanerjee Good Sudeep. Would you be able to accept my answer as the right answer then?

Comment: Sure Anil. This is just a mitigation. We still will have to work to a solution.The Kaa Management console still do not provide any facility to provide the domain name instead of the IP address. Not all can avail servers on cloud. There is a mechanism of port forwarding also. I will work on it and try to find out the approach.